# POST data in JavaScript is not being sent

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my JavaScript code to post to my API:

```
var pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

pageRequest.open("POST", "/api.php", true);

pageRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (pageRequest.readyState === 4 && pageRequest.status === 200) {
        console.log(pageRequest.responseText);
    }
}

pageRequest.send("firstname=John&lastname=Doe");
```

And here is my PHP backend code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"])) {
    $first_name = $_POST["firstname"];
    $last_name = $_POST["lastname"];

    echo "Hello, " . htmlspecialchars($first_name) . " " . htmlspecialchars($last_name);
} else {
    echo "Please include all fields.";
}

?>
```

However, my PHP code just echos "Please include all fields.", and when I try doing

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

It returns an empty array. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely missing setup of request header:

```
var pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

pageRequest.open("POST", "/api.php", true);

pageRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (pageRequest.readyState === 4 && pageRequest.status === 200) {
        console.log(pageRequest.responseText);
    }
}

***    pageRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

pageRequest.send("firstname=John&lastname=Doe");
```